# How do I figure out what nodes I'm connected to and who is sending what to who?

Tags: p2p, nodes, peer, daemon, network

When I type `print_cn` into the daemon, I see a lot of OUT and IN entries.

Does OUT mean that I am sending information OUT to that peer, or is that peer sending information to me? Or is it a two-way connection? If I see an IN connection, is that connection connecting to me?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's a two way connection, the IN refers to connections initiated by the peer, and OUT refers to connections initiated by your node, but communication is duplex.

In that status command, the X+Y part is X OUT connections and Y in connections. You're connected to all of these nodes, the only difference is which side initiated the connection.

Answer (score 4):

Pretty sure that's how it works. You can also use the command "status" and you'll see at the end of the line a number like "8+1" this shows the number of nodes you are connected to, and after the + shows the number of nodes you are serving.